# Mongoose deep populate() returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need a help on mongoose deep population. Basically, I have an `ItemGroupSchema` having a `_id` referenced to `ItemSchema` and `items` being an array of references to `ItemSchema` as well.

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IItem>({
    // information fields about item type, quantity, model, size,...
}); // its model is ItemModel

const ItemGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IItemGroup>({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: ItemModel.modelName },
    items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: ItemModel.modelName }]
}, { _id: false }); // its model is ItemGroupModel
```

From a valid `_id` input, I do the following:

1. Get the `items` of it from `ItemGroupModel`; done.
2. With the `items` of `_id` I got, I populate it from ItemGroupSchema so I can have `items` of `items` of `_id`; done.
3. Now, I should have `items` of `items` inside `items` of `_id`. Next is to populate only on `items` of `_id` from `ItemSchema` to have some information to work on, which is not done yet.

The issue is that, `populate()` operation of the last step gives me an empty `items` array. Below is how each operation looks like step by step:

```
1.
ItemGroupModel.find({ _id: 'root' });
{
  _id: 'root',
  items: ['parent1', 'parent2']
}

2.
ItemGroupModel.find({ _id: 'root' }).populate({ path: 'items', model: ItemGroupModel.modelName });
{
  _id: 'root',
  items: [
    { _id: 'parent1', items: ['child1', 'child2'] },
    { _id: 'parent2', items: ['child3']
  ]
}

3.
ItemGroupModel.find({ _id: 'root' }).populate({ path: 'items', model: ItemGroupModel.modelName, populate: { path: '_id', model: ItemModel.modelName }});
{
  _id: 'root',
  items: [] // yes, empty
}

// I expect it to be
{
  _id: 'root',
  items: [
    { _id: { _id: 'parent1', type: 'gun', quantity: 1, size: 1 }, items: ['child1', 'child2'] },
    { _id: { _id: 'parent2', type: 'backpack', quantity: 1, size: 1 }, items: ['child3']
  ]
}
```

Comment: you want to use populate or you could use `$lookup` ?

Comment: Oohhh, how didn't i come up with this way earlier? 
`$lookup` really does the job for me, thanks a lot!
I cannot give you a REP due to commenting, I guess

Comment: do you want to make a answer and accept it ?

Comment: sure thing, please do it and i'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this aggregation on ItemSchema collection

```
[{
  from: 'ItemGroup',
  localField: 'items',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'items'

}]
```